# aws codedeploy policy for lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

I'm using AWS ECS and to blue/green deploy, also using Codedeploy.

I trigger lambda on before install in codedeploy for specific job.

But Codedeploy stuck on before install.

So I inspect lambda logs on cloudwatch, and it executed perfectly.

I think codedeploy do not know lambda was finished.

Is there any policy need for execute lambda on codedeploy?

Any comments, very appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Potential reasons could be either of below :

1. For the lifecycle events execution is all depends on the Code Deploy Agent at the first place which must be installed on either EC2 instances or even if its a container service like ECS.
   You might have missed to install the Code Deploy Agent on the machine/container. Below are the set of commands which can help you install the same on your container, also you can pass these set of commands as **bootstrap script** in your container.

> sudo yum update
>
> sudo yum install aws-cli
>
> cd /home/ec2-user
>
> aws s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest/install . --region
>   us-east-1
>
> chmod +x ./install
>
> sudo ./install auto

2. There might be error in your appspec.yml, if that is the case then you may be able to see that error in which lifecycle event the error is there. To identify that, go to the deployments => select one of the deployments which got failed => go to events => here you will see the error => clicking on that error will display the reason.
   If you want to understand in detail how it works, kindly go through my blog [here](https://kddeveops.blogspot.com/2019/03/create-continuous-integration-pipeline.html), although its for EC2.

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't codedeploy agent issue. Because if I do not hook lambda, it deployed successfully.

Comment: And I do not have `appspec.yml`. Just trigger before hook via ECS service update.